# How to show dynamic news and news archive in WordPress.com

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I am creating website using free plan on WordPress.com

What plugin should used in WordPress for displaying short news highlights; on homepage; with read more link which  jumps to detailed news?

Can we use the same in WordPress.com? If not than any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Vazafh layout for many items you can use [Page Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) plugin here.

Other plugins like Fusion Core that you can use them